# Scaling numbers with constraints

Tags: mathematical-statistics, linear-algebra, optimal-scaling

I have four numbers $X_1$, $X_2$, $X_3$ and $X_4$ that range from [-2,2]. I want to scale these numbers ($x_1=scaled(X_1)$) with the following constraints:

$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=1,$$
subject to $$x_1+x_2<1,$$ $$x_2+x_4<1,$$ $$x_3+x_4<1,$$ $$x_1+x_3<1.$$
The $x_i$ can be between $[-\infty,\infty]$, as long as the constraints above are satisfied.
How can this be achieved?

Comment: Why? What are you trying to achieve by that? You could replace each value with 0.25 and the constraints would hold, but I guess there are also some other assumptions that you are making that you didn't mention.

Comment: Does "scaling" mean applying a (nontrivial, meaning that the multiplier is nonzero) linear transformation?

Comment: Im trying to achieve weights that sum to 100% and the subweights also sum to 100%. The X_i's are Betas in a regression and I want to scale these Betas into weights, that sum to 1, and has the constraints listed above.

Comment: What for? This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If those are parameters of the model, why not just use constrained optimization with those constraints?

Comment: Because I need a formula so that I can do this for rolling 24month periods, of course for a one time solution it would be easier to add constraints to the optimization, but I'm trying to figure out a way to make it scalable (for thousands of regressions) and also easily updatable with new data.

Answer (score 1):

How do you want to treat negative individual values?  Your constraints also require all pairs to add to values greater than $0$ as well as less than $1$, which suggests to me that you have some issues with negative weights.

You could try something like $$\mathrm{scaled}(X_i) = \frac{X_i-\min\{X_j,0\}}{\sum\limits_k\left(X_k-\min\{X_j,0\}\right)}$$
on some examples of your choosing.  It requires the $X_i$ not to be all equal to some non-positive value, and if they were all equal then $\mathrm{scaled}(X_i)=\frac14$ would be the obvious choice